# Wait for socket_write to complete before writing again

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I need to send some data from a PHP server to a Node server.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far on the PHP side:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$result = socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', '3000');
socket_write($socket, "Hello World", 11);
socket_close($socket);
```

Running this code successfully sends the message to my Node server and outputs this.

However I need to send more than one message back to the socket. I actually need to send several thousand responses. But if I were to call the `socket_write()` function within a loop like so:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$result = socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', '3000');
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
    socket_write($socket, "Hello World", 11);
}
socket_close($socket);
```

it seems to append all the data together and send it in one go at the end of the script. I need to send the data back in real time. Is there any way I can do this in PHP?

Comment: Where your socket send successfull answer ? How to will be sure resources is available ? Send , take a successful message, send again. If you don't need answer why using socket ? Serve as static file.

Comment: @dsgdfg I don't need to receive confirmation that the Node server received the data. If the connection to the socket fails, I throw an exception

Comment: @dsgdfg Do you think I should get the Node server to return a success response then? Maybe that would be my only way of telling PHP that it's cool to go to the next iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through many PHP socket libraries, I noticed that nearly all of them just implement a `usleep(1000000)` after sending a socket. I'm not sure if this is the best method, but maybe it's the only way due to PHP's limitations.

In the end, I decided to store the time that data was last written to a socket. Then, calculate the time elapsed since then and subtract that from 1000000 microseconds. This way, the script will not wait longer than necessary.

```
public function send(array $payload){
    $json = json_encode($payload);
    $write = socket_write($this->socket, $json, strlen($json);
    $sleep_time = 1000000 - (microtime(true) - $this->last_sent);
    if($sleep_time > 0) usleep($sleep_time);
    $this->last_sent = microtime(true);
    return $write !== false ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I am also running into problems where `socket_write` seems to have appended multiple JSON objects together. Did you ever figure out exactly why this happens? Are implementing the `usleep(1000000)` solution everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Stephan-v my vague guess is that when the socket gets sent, if one is still being sent, they end up getting jumbled together. I actually wrote a little class which uses the above solution: https://github.com/danjohnson95/PHP-Socket-Emitter

Comment: Good stuff, thanks. It will help me out with my project. I still want to know what causes this exactly though :)

Comment: @Stephan-v me too. I’ll do some more research today and come back to you with my findings. Best of luck with your project