# JSON encoded buffer data not encoding properly

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, symfony, websocket

I am currently trying to `json_encode` some buffer data and decoding it on a `node.js` websocket server unsuccessfully.

I am using a docker container which supplies me ANSI data which I format to HTML.

I use the [Symfony Process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output) to get real-time process output from the docker container and use `socket_write` to output it to my `Node.js` websocket server.

My code for writing the data from docker with `socket_write` to the `Node.js` server looks like this:

```
$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) use ($socket, $converter) {
    $html = $converter->convert($buffer);

    // Pass the room we want to send the HTML socket messages to.
    $data = [
        'html' => $html,
        'room' => 'http://arbiter.dev/stephan-v/arbiter-test'
    ];

    $json = json_encode($data);

    socket_write($socket, $json, strlen($json));
});
```

On my server I try to decode the `json_encoded` data like so:

```
socket.on('data', (msg) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(msg);
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('log', data.html.toString().trim());
});
```

This fails with a syntax error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 66

When I `console.log` the incoming `msg` on my `Node.js` server I get this as output:

```
Websocket server online, listening on port :5600
<Buffer 7b 22 68 74 6d 6c 22 3a 22 3c 73 70 61 6e 20 73 74 79 6c 65 3d 5c 22 62 61 63 6b 67 72 6f 75 6e 64 2d 63 6f 6c 6f 72 3a 20 23 30 37 33 36 34 32 3b 20 ... >
<Buffer 7b 22 68 74 6d 6c 22 3a 22 3c 73 70 61 6e 20 73 74 79 6c 65 3d 5c 22 62 61 63 6b 67 72 6f 75 6e 64 2d 63 6f 6c 6f 72 3a 20 23 30 37 33 36 34 32 3b 20 ... >
<Buffer 7b 22 68 74 6d 6c 22 3a 22 22 2c 22 72 6f 6f 6d 22 3a 22 68 74 74 70 3a 5c 2f 5c 2f 61 72 62 69 74 65 72 2e 64 65 76 5c 2f 73 74 65 70 68 61 6e 2d 76 ... >
<Buffer 7b 22 68 74 6d 6c 22 3a 22 22 2c 22 72 6f 6f 6d 22 3a 22 68 74 74 70 3a 5c 2f 5c 2f 61 72 62 69 74 65 72 2e 64 65 76 5c 2f 73 74 65 70 68 61 6e 2d 76 ... >
undefined:1
{"html":"","room":"http:\/\/arbiter.dev\/stephan-v\/arbiter-test"}{"html":"","room":"http:\/\/arbiter.dev\/stephan-v\/arbiter-test"}
                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 66
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

So it seems the `msg` is a buffer stream but still the `JSON.parse` seems to work on it for the first couple of messages.

Then for about the third message I am sending to my socket it fails. What is going on here?

Is my buffer simply not aware that my messages should be chunked into proper pieces since I am seeing 2 `JSON` objects glued together on my last `console.log` statement?

Comment: With networking you can never depend on how data is chunked,.  That's why most protocols have a length indicator, so it knows how many bytes are required to finish this message, and then ready for next.

Comment: How is this a `websocket` issue? Are you using raw TCP/IP or the Websocket protocol? Two different things.

Comment: My `socket_write` is a string length as a third argument like so: `strlen($json)` is this where it goes wrong then? Can it not calculate the proper length or am I going over the limit or something?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved my problem completely:

[Wait for socket_write to complete before writing again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400980/wait-for-socket-write-to-complete-before-writing-again)

The problem is that I do not understand why. As my third argument for `socket_write` I pass in the length of my JSON object like so:

```
socket_write($socket, $json, strlen($json));
```

I know I need to set a length because it is simply a stream and it accepts "chunks" of data in the buffer so to speak.

But shouldn't the `strlen($json)` already solve all of my problems?

Why does my `socket_write` messages still sometimes append multiple JSON objects together?

**Edit**

From what I have been reading since these sockets work with TCP the chunking of data seems to happen because of [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) and are chunked depending on message size and when the last message has been acknowledged.

PHP has introduces a `TCP_NODELAY` in PHP 7.1 but the Algorithm is there for a reason so you need to be wary about this.

I guess the best way to fix this is simply splitting up the message on the server side yourself by splitting on a delimiter you have added in PHP.

Correct my if I am wrong on any of this, I would love to hear thoughts about this.